# use node js in a php framework

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io, silex

I'm currently using the silex micro-framework on my project and recently discovered node js to include socket.io to my project.
My question is, how can i use both of those technologies in my project ?

I found a few answers on the web but nothing good and I'm sure it's no big deal.

Someone to help me ?

Comment: well i have bad ratings now, i m not sure to know why .. just want to know if it's possible and if it is, how to set it up

Comment: Seriously, what did you expect from a question like "_how can i use both of those technologies in my project?_". A very broad question like this one is not useful at all (_and off-topic on SO_). You should go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then, if you are sure your question fits the SO rules, read [How to Ask a Question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a good question and get some help.

Comment: well i don t know who you think you are saying my question is useless, but  i think the purpose of those kinds of website is to help people with particulary cases, mine being that i don t know how to use node.js in a php project ! i don t know what's wrong about my question knowing that i couldn't find any help elsewhere and that my english is not so good .. thanks anyway i know what to expect next time i ask a question around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Gearman. [docs is here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php)

Code a "worker" in node and add jobs for that worker in php.

I understand my answer is not detailed as to how to code the Gearman worker and how to add jobs to the Gearman job Queue. But this is a way that will work. We do that where I work to offload the validation of huge chunks of JSON against a JSON schema. The app is in php but node.js is probably 100x faster than php to validate JSON against a schema...so we have best of both worlds :)

Basically, read Gearman's documentation and you will be able to do what you want to do.